# How to generate this matrix with armadillo in c++?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I would like to generate a matrix in C ++ using armadillo that behaves like a "truth table", for example:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

I was thinking of a cycle of this kind, but I'm not very practical with armadillo and its data structures.

```
imat A = zeros<imat>(8, 3);

/* fill each row */
for(int i=0; i < 8; i++)
{
    A.row(i) = (i/(pow(2, i)))%2 * ones<ivec>(3).t();  // 
}

cout << "A = \n" << A << endl;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i wouldnt use `pow` to get powers of 2, otherwise I dont understand what is wrong with the code you have

Comment: BTW, a more efficient method of calculating `pow(2,x)` is `1<<x`, called bit shifting.  Many processors can perform a bit shift with one instruction.

Comment: I highly recommend getting your algorithms working on a desktop computer before porting to the Armadillo.  You can port the C++ easily to the Armadillo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a large size *truth table* matrix (~`2^30` x `30`) as you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289709/matrix-with-vectors-why-with-large-number), from the memory point of view, you should implement a function which quickly calculates the values you want rather than storing them on a matrix.

This is easily done using `std::bitset` as follows.
Note that `N` must be determined at compile-time in this method.
Then you can get the value of your `A(i,j)` by `matrix<3>(i,j)`:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rcFwHTXu7V89s9LR)

```
#include <bitset>

template <std::size_t N>
std::size_t matrix(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
{
    return std::bitset<N>(i)[N-j-1];
}
```

Comment: Good job on finding the related post, pinpoint the X-Y problem and providing a working solution.